# How to AddHandler to Multiple Items and Properly Reference Said Handler

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a program wherein I need to create GotFocus and LostFocus event handlers for every text box.

What I have now creates an error whenever any text box in the form is clicked on:

```
Private Sub lblTotalWeight_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each cnt In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
            AddHandler cnt.GotFocus, AddressOf txtBox_GotFocus
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtBox_GotFocus(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim textBox As TextBox = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
        textBox.ForeColor = Color.White
        textBox.BackColor = Color.LightGray
    End Sub
```

I'm getting an error with the Dim textBox as TextBox = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox), and I have no idea why or how to fix it.

There will be another Private Sub for a lost focus event that will be nearly identical, if it helps.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You do not need to write `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` event handlers for anything.  If you had read the appropriate documentation you would know that, as an application developer, you should be handling the `Enter` and `Leave` events.

Comment: Also, while it's not wrong, you don't really have to use `AddHandler` in those situations. You can select all the `TextBoxes` in the designer and then use the Properties window to create a common event handler. I prefer that way, although it will not work automatically for new controls the way the code you have will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
```

returns an `IEnumerable(Of TextBox)`.  It's not a single `Textbox` so you can't assign it to a `TextBox` variable.  You need to access the `TextBox` that raised the event:

```
Dim textBox As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
```

In an event handler, the `sender` parameter is always the object that raised the event.

Answer (score 4):

`Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)` returns a list of controls that are textboxes. It works great in your `AddHandler` call, but in your event handler you need to use `sender as Textbox` instead.

```
 Dim textBox As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, Textbox)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)` with replace `CType(sender, TextBox)` for event `txtBox_GotFocus`